# How to Change State of Material Button after a Delay?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-text

I have a List of Emojis, `[, , , , , , , , , , , , , ]` with me, I also have a Button With me with no Icon Associated with it. See this Material Button.

```
                     MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        
                        child: Text("",textScaleFactor: 2),
                        shape: CircleBorder(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      ),
```

Now, I need to Show up the Above list, `[, , , , , , , , , , , , , ]` after a Delay of 1 sec, inside this Button.

Comment: you need  `Timer.periodic` then

Comment: Can you Explain me more About that, @pskink

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html - you can check a small example there

Comment: What About, Showing List one by one?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Future.

```
MaterialButton(
 onPressed: () async {
     await Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
     // your function
     },
 child: Text('', textScaleFactor: 2),
 shape: CircleBorder(),
 padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
),
```

Comment: So I need to Put my For Loop or Something just below the await thing that Davor's Code is Specifying?

Comment: Can you explain me, how can i show up list, one by one in the placce of Icon in the Material Button

Answer (score 1):

You can use Timer.periodic to achieve this. See this sample code

[Link to docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer-class.html)

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Timer emojiTimer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    emojiTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      changeEmoji();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  int randomInt = 0;
  Future<void> changeEmoji() async {
    setState(() {
      var ran = Random();
      randomInt = ran.nextInt(emojiList.length);
    });
  }

  var emojiList = [
    "",
    "",
    " ",
    "",
    " ",
    " ",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('hello there'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          emojiTimer.cancel();
        },
        child: Text(emojiList[randomInt]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```